# Read text data from Flash

Tags: flash, text, get

How can I read embedded text inside Flash?

For example, [on this website](http://www.bet365.com/home/FlashGen4/WebConsoleApp.asp?) there are results of games in flash format ("Chelsea - Liverpool 0-0").

How to get "Chelsea - Liverpool 0-0" from there?

Comment: Can you add some details around what you need to do with the text once you have it? The approach, if there is one, may vary depending on that.

Comment: Can you add some details around what you need to do with the text once you have it? the question was how to get the text from flash, not on what he wants to do with it"@marty

Comment: @parele Different goals have different solutions, even when they all involve the same problems.

Comment: i was playing your gamez on your blog the other day, are the gamez current or there older projects, by the way i will delet these comments later

Comment: @parele They're all *extremely* old (2007 or earlier). I haven't had a chance to work on any projects of my own since I started work :(

Comment: fair enough, thats all i seemed to do is make flash apps for the sake of it, wouldnt mind getting paid for it though.I also tried XNA frame work several years ago. I gave up cause im no good at 3d design objects and what not. and your right i cant spell at all "CHANGED my Answer".

Answer (score 0):

bQ# How can I read embedded text inside Flash????

You cant grab them scores from the flash movie itself unless you have full access to their server and or that flash file.

You can look around for providers who have allowed public to gain access to this information, My self had 2 Battlefield servers which I was able to grap game stats using Fsocket(); in php then importing them into flash. So to be able to do this i had used the Battlefield API and had to make request for this info via php/json back to php to flash.

To elaborate aswell shared hosting generally wont allow this type of comunication between servers(Fsocket(); so i was forced to rent a VPS.